# Achieve a smooth scale transition in parent and children div simultaneously

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms, easing

I am trying to scale a div and make its children look like it stays in the same place while the parent scales. To achieve it I am scaling the parent, and the children inversely:

```
        Children-scale  Parent-scale
start   2               0.5           -> 2 * 0.5 = 1
middle  1.5             0.75          -> 1.5 * 0.75 = 1.125 [It should be 1]
end     1               1             -> 1
```

As can be seen in the demo, the initial and final values are correct but not the intermediates. At first I thought it could be the easing function, but assigning a linear (constant speed) makes no difference. Possibly assigning an [inverse easing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139790) could do it, but I am asking if there is a non-mathematical way to achieve this (as I am not confident with bezier curves).

How could I achieve a smooth transition using the transform scale property?

```js
var $div = $('div');

$div.on('click', function() {

    $div.toggleClass('scaled');

});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
div, img {
    transition: transform 1s linear;/* Other easing function make no difference */
 /* transform-origin:left top; Makes no difference */
}
div.scaled {
 transform:scaleY(0.5);
}
div.scaled img {
 transform:scaleY(2);/* 1 / 0.5 */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Click the image</span>
<div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/sbyPaAsl.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezcbj219/).

---

**Edit**:

Using CSS animations and assigning the correct values each x%, I get something close but still not perfect. (This also needs to know beforehand the scale value or otherwise create the animation and assign it with JavaScript.)

```js
var $div = $('div');

$div.on('click', function() {

    $div.toggleClass('scaled');

});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
 overflow:hidden;
}
img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
div.scaled {
    animation: ddiv 1s linear;
}
div.scaled img {
    animation: iimg 1s linear;
}
@keyframes iimg {
    0% {transform:scaleY(2);}
    20% {transform:scaleY(1.8);}
    40% {transform:scaleY(1.6);}
    60% {transform:scaleY(1.4);}
    80% {transform:scaleY(1.2);}
    100% {transform:scaleY(1);}
}
@keyframes ddiv {
    0% {transform:scaleY(0.5);}
    20% {transform:scaleY(0.555);}/* 1 / 1.8 */
    40% {transform:scaleY(0.625);}/* 1 / 1.6 */
    60% {transform:scaleY(0.714);}/* 1 / 1.4 */
    80% {transform:scaleY(0.833);}/* 1 / 1.2 */
    100% {transform:scaleY(1);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Click the image</span>
<div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/sbyPaAsl.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am posting an answer to the question as I found a bezier curve by testing values which is close to the desired result; but I am still open to other answers if someone has a better approach.

The function is `1/x`. The scale-up element needs a linear easing, and the scale-down one a `cubic-bezier(.25,.48,.52,.75)` (it is not the exact curve). This way the children element almost looks like it is not scaling.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezcbj219/2/)

```js
var $div = $('div');

$div.on('click', function() {

    $div.toggleClass('scaled');

});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
 overflow:hidden;
}
img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    transition: transform 1s linear;
}
img {
    transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(.25,.48,.52,.75);
}
div.scaled {
    transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(.25,.48,.52,.75);
 transform:scaleY(0.5);
}
div.scaled img {
    transition: transform 1s linear;
 transform:scaleY(2);/* 1 / 0.5 */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/sbyPaAsl.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would an approach using `pseudoelements` work for you instead?

Here's an idea:

```js
var $div = $('div');

$div.on('click', function() {

  $div.toggleClass('scaled');

});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

div:after,
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: white;
}

div:before {
  top: 0;
}

div:after {
  bottom: 0;
}

div.scaled:after,
div.scaled:before {
  transition: height 1s linear;
}

div.scaled:after,
div.scaled:before {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Click the image</span>
<div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/sbyPaAsl.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is a very smart way, but I'm afraid not valid for the scenario. There is background content (which is actually changing while this transition happens), that is why I am using the `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: I see. Could the image also be added as background content?

Comment: Do you mean a background-image of the div rather than an <img>?

Comment: Yes, a background-image

Comment: Well, the image needs to be there after the transition but I see no problem in hiding it, and applying it as a `background-image` of the div while the transition happens.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it's useful for your situation or not:

But if you don't need the overflow-hidden in the container, making it and the child rotate could give you a posibility:

```js
var $div = $('div');

$div.on('click', function() {

    $div.toggleClass('scaled');

});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid 1px green;
}
img {
    width: auto;
    height: 50%;
    top: 25%;
}
div, img {
  transition: transform 1s linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}
div.scaled {
 transform: rotateX(60deg);
}
div.scaled img {
 transform: rotateX(-60deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Click the image</span>
<div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/sbyPaAsl.jpg" alt=""></div>
```